# Give Children Unique ID's

Tags: categories, menus, navigation, children, sub-menu

Is there a way I can give each wordpress children (subcategory UL lists) unique ID's? I'm creating a dropdown list for subcategories and I want to position them but `:nth-child` isn't supported by everything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know, all menu items already have unique ID´s ("menu-item-XX"), may they be first or second level. the UL itself has a different class :
`menu` for first level and `sub-menu` for second. 
hence , in css for example 
`.menu li` and `.sub-menu li` will give you the differentiation for styling.
you could also do that without the unique id or classes , by simply targeting the different levels of the menu,
`.menu UL LI` for first level `.menu UL LI UL LI` for second
Anotehr alternative is to use javascript or jQuery.. But I think this is not what you want here ..

**EDIT I** I forgot to mention that one can also add classes in the menu editor itself on item base , and also the  has class arguments..Not to mention the fact that you can create 2 custom-menus wih your name*

**EDIT II** If you really want a custom function (everyone these days wants one..) than this one will add a class to each menu item which is equal to the menu title.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'dl_menu_class_by_title', 10, 2 );
function dl_menu_class_by_title($classes, $item) {
        $classes[] = $item->title;
    return $classes;
}
```

.. But I still stand by my first answer that in 98% of the cases -  it is an unnecessary overkill ..

Edit III - since you are unable to implement none of the above ways to solution (all valid) - Here is The jQuery way :

```
 <script>
$(function(){
    var i =0;
 $('ul.sub-menu').addClass (function(idx) {

     return "item-" + idx;
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Well I'm trying to think as dynamically as possible here. I think if the admin changes the subcategories won't the menu-item-xx change also?

Comment: yes, the menu-item-xx ID will change, but not the classes.. this should be enough for simple styling. if you want to do something more elaborated, please describe it ... (and also read my edit)

Comment: Well I'm talking about the UL's. not each seperate list item. I want to give `.children` ID's of the parent category or something similar. That way I can move each list item exactly where I want them.

Comment: The UL already has a class of it´s own . and you could also change it via <?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?> (one argument is the UL ID and other is CLASS) . Could you explain what you want to achieve that is not achievable by simple CSS and classes (assuming you have a basic knowladge of CSS)? I do not fully understand what is the problem of moving the items with the default behaviour of wordpress Nav_menu, like 99 % of the websites are doing. If you care to post your code and problem, Maybe I could help better..

Comment: I think your over thinking it. I just want unique IDs on each child UL so then I can move each UL separately instead of together (like I would have to do with a class) but I'm also keeping it all dynamic so I don't want to use the menu-item-xx (plus its a class which is not what I want). Right now I have the navigation pulling in dynamically via wp_list_categories(). I was looking in the admin `nav` files to see if I could add an argument and in incremeneter that would auto add an id of `id=blah1` etc. And really the only code I have is wp_list_categories() and css.

Comment: I believe that @krembo99 is right . There is no apparent problem is styling the menu with the default classes. You have few levels of UL LI that you can use. in terms of css - this should be a no-brainer. Krembo99 is not the one "overt thinking" it , if something, it might be the other way around ..

Comment: if I want each menu to display differently or to be styled differently I can't use classes. If I position a class or style a class this style will be applied to All my "child ULs" where as I want to style each child UL differently. I don't want to use the class IDs that come on parent classes because that might change at some point and I would have to go back in and rechange all my styles. If I give each child UL a unique ID I can style each one differently/position it differently no matter what the parent ID is.

Comment: I still do not understand why you can not use none of the above methods (the most obvious one for beginners would be to use 2 menus) , but I have also added the jQuery way. If that also can not work for you - I am out of Ideas..

Comment: The jquery one works perfect. This way I can style each UL differently and it won't matter what a categories ID is so I can change them whenever! Thanks!